# After Converting Seconds to Minutes & Seconds not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display `2700` as `45:00` in javascript, but it is not displayed. I tried this:

```js
var checkStatet = function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'check_diffex.php?od=$sdsst'
  }).done(function(data) {
    var o = 2700;
    var minutes = Math.floor(o / 60);
    var seconds = o - minutes * 60;
    var tit = minutes + ':' + seconds;
    var time = jQuery('#rbtntime');
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
      time.html(tit);
      o--;
    }, 1000)
  });
}

checkStatet();
```

```html
<div id="rbtntime"></div>
```

I am unable to find out the mistake.

Comment: Why are you trying to divide 0 by 60?  Also `minutes:seconds` isn't a valid way to concatenate numbers into a string.  And as it is, the interval is doing nothing.  Changing the value of `o` does not change the value of `tit`

Comment: Press F12 in your browser and check for errors. You have got a syntax error here: `minutes:seconds`.

Comment: @Taplar Sorry it is By mistake, changing that to `o` it is not displaying.

Comment: `var tit = minutes:seconds;` that is not how string concatenation works.
You need to use `var tit = minutes + ":" + seconds;` or ``var tit = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;``

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to consider renaming the variables in your code? especially the `minutes + ":" + seconds` variable? :P

Comment: Lots of different issues here, :)

Comment: @Taplar Changing the value of `o` does not change the value of `tit`.. So how to do that?

Comment: I would say extract the method out into a named function that accepts the value of the `o` as a parameter.  Then you can change your logic to call that with the decremented o value.

Comment: @Taplar CanI have code edits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var checkStatet = function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'check_diffex.php?od=$sdsst'
  }).done(function(data) {
    //lookup the element just once
    var time = jQuery('#rbtntime');
    //initialize the time
    var o = 2700;

    //start loop delay
    setTimeout(function countdown(){
      var minutes = Math.floor(o / 60);
      var seconds = o % 60;
      //update the time
      time.html(minutes.toString() + ':' + seconds.toString());
      //decrement the time for next iteration
      o--;
      //so long as time is not zero, loop
      if (o > 0) setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
    }, 1000);
  });

}

checkStatet();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to divide 0 by 60

```
var minutes = Math.floor(0 / 60);
```

When it's

```
var minutes = Math.floor(o / 60);
```

Comment: Sorry it is By mistake, changing that to `o` it is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tit = minutes:seconds;
```

should probably be

```
var tit = minutes + ':' + seconds;
```

But you also divide 0 by 60, which is a bit strange.

Comment: @NamarsahaMNetworking That is because the function you pass to `setInterval` contains only this code `time.html(tit);
  o--;`. Even thought you decrease the seconds you don't change the value of `tit`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `4700` seconds is `78.3333` minutes, not `45`. I assume you mean `2700` instead.

Secondly, to solve the issue, divide the input by `60` and round it down to get minutes, then use the modulo operator to get the remaining seconds, like this:

```js
var secs = 2700;
var $time = $('#time');

function updateTime(input) {
  var mins = ('0' + (Math.floor(input / 60))).slice(-2);
  var seconds = ('0' + (input % 60)).slice(-2);
  $time.text(`${mins}:${seconds}`);
}

setInterval(function() {
  secs--;
  updateTime(secs);
}, 1000)

updateTime(secs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for alerting, and please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059281/after-converting-seconds-to-minutes-seconds-not-displaying?noredirect=1#comment81066179_47059281

Comment: See my updated answer. Note that all the code in the snippet should be placed in your `done()` handler.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this helps me, but can you please update as per my question...

Comment: It already is. If you need further assistance please be clear.